# Active NavItem when component first run

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm attempting to render a nested `Nav` using react-bootstrap that should only be shown when a given `NavItem` outside its scope is active. Something like the following:

```
<Nav bsStyle="tabs" stacked onSelect={this.onSelect.bind(this)}>
  <LinkContainer to="/foo">
    <NavItem href="#">Foo</NavItem>
  </LinkContainer>

  <li className="nested">
    <Nav bsStyle="tabs" stacked>
      <LinkContainer to="/foo/bar">
        <NavItem href="#">Foo/bar</NavItem>
      </LinkContainer>
    </Nav>
  </li>
</Nav>
```

The idea is for the nested `li` above to be shown when the top `NavItem` is active.

However, how do I find out which `NavItem` is active when the component is first run so as to apply a special CSS class to the nested `li`? The problem is that `onSelect` isn't fired in the `Nav` for the active nav item and there doesn't seem to be an obvious way of finding this out.

I've inspected the props of the `NavItem` (child of `LinkContainer`, child of `Nav`) and its `active` prop is not set to `true` when it is supposed to.

**EDIT:** I should qualify that I'm interested in knowing how to achieve this without having to specify a `ref` prop for every `NavItem` that owns/controls a nested element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `Tabs` so the nested `<li>` will be in under the `Tab` you want, and it'll be shown only when it's active.